# Change AI clothing selection

Tags: the-sims-4

Is there a way to force all the AI to select clothing from a specific list?
For example, I want everyone to dress in business suits, or certain custom clothing.
I would want this for all the NPC's in the game.
Or is there maybe a way to ban clothing so I can just ban everything, except for what I want, like using a whitelist or blacklist?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible by default, but there exists a mod for this by [littlemssam](https://littlemssam.tumblr.com/post/175405300963/dress-code-custom-lot-traits-this-mod-adds-six) called '*Dress Code | Custom Lot Traits*':

> This Mod adds six new custom Lot Traits to the Game which lets you customize every Lot what Sims should wear.
>
> When Sims spawn on a Lot where one of the seven Lot Traits (see below) is active, they’ll change into a specific Outfit Category.
>
> The Traits need to be added to the Lot before your Sims will spawn there!
> Only use one Trait per Lot!
>
> Dress Code Traits available (works on every Lot):
>
> - Athletic
> - Swimwear
> - Formal
> - Party
> - Sleepwear
> - Everyday
> - Naked Addon